# Need help on Bootstrap - Beginner (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css

I'm currently learning how Bootstrap works. As you can see there, it's a simple HTML page, it seems that only the background was applied in the CSS file. However, the next two modifications I did, did not apply. Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you!

[HTML page](https://gyazo.com/941fc487b904f8bc048bd7e30df6b2ce)

[CSS page](https://gyazo.com/bc810a44392ecf6994aeed6c29dbe394)

[website screenshot](https://gyazo.com/f5344aca870a11f1b429fca66e0fb02b)

Comment: maybe take out the semicolons after the curly braces in the css, those aren't necessary, could be causing an issue

Comment: Please add an [mcve] to your post rather than linking to third party pages, and worse, embedding them as code to circumvent the system restrictions on posting links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the semicolons after the curly braces in the css, they shouldn't be there.